# find non browsable activity using package manager in android

Tags: android, android-intent, package-managers

I used the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER` flag to check if the founded activity is browser or not but this flag only works in android 11 or higher. I need this in lower android version what should I do?

```
private boolean openInAppIfPossible(String url) {
    try {
        Activity activity = ActivityHolder.getInstance().getCurrentActivity();
        PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
        intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER);
        ResolveInfo info = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (info != null) {
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    return false;
}
```